# Extracting a pattern (grep output) in Linux from shell?

Tags: shell, grep

Grep output is usually like this:

```
after/ftplugin/python.vim:49:  setlocal number
```

Is it possible for me extract the file name and line number from this result using standard linux utilities ? Looking for a generic solution that works pretty well .

I can think of using awk to get the first string like :

Input

```
echo 'after/ftplugin/python.vim:49:  setlocal number' | awk 'print $1' 
'after/ftplugin/python.vim:49:'
$
```

Expected

```
after/ftplugin/python.vim and 49
```

Goal  : Open in Vim

I am writing a small function that transforms the grep output to something vim can understand - mostly for academic purpose . I know there are thinks like Ack.vim out there which does something similar . What are the standard light weight utils out there ?

Edit: `grep -n "text to find" file.ext |cut -f1 -d:` seems to do it if you dont mind double parsing the string . Sed though needs to be used !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "reverse parse" you mean you want to start from the end (and can safely assume that the file content contains no colons), parameter expansion makes that easy:

```
line='after/ftplugin/python.vim:49:  setlocal number'
name_and_lineno=${line%:*}
name=${name_and_lineno%:*}
lineno=${name_and_lineno##*:}
```

Being all in-process (using shell built-in functionality), this is much faster than using external tools such as sed, awk, etc.

To connect it all together, consider a loop such as the following:

```
while read -r line; do
  ...
done < <(grep ...)
```

---

Now, to handle all possible filenames (including ones with colons) *and* all possible content (including strings with colons), you need a grep with GNU extensions:

```
while IFS='' read -u 4 -r -d '' file \
          && read -u 4 -r -d ':' lineno \
          && read -u 4 -r line; do
  vim "+$lineno" "$file"
done 4< <(grep -HnZ -e "string to find" /dev/null file)
```

This works as follows:

- Use `grep -Z` (a GNU extension) to terminate each filename with a NUL rather than a `:`
- Use `IFS='' read -r -d ''` to read until the first NUL when reading filenames
- Use `read -r -d ':' lineno` to read until a colon when reading line numbers
- Read until the next newline when reading lines
- Redirect contents on FD #4 to avoid overriding stdin, stdout or stderr (so vim will still work properly)
- Use the `-u 4` argument on all calls to `read` to handle contents from FD #4

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `Bash` you can do it this way:

```
IFS=: read FILE NUM __ < <(exec grep -Hn "string to find" file)
vim "+$NUM" "$FILE"
```

Or POSIX:

```
IFS=: read FILE NUM __ <<EOD
$(grep -Hn "string to find" file)
EOD
vim "+$NUM" "$FILE"
```

Style © konsolebox :)

Answer (score 2):

This will do:

```
echo 'after/ftplugin/python.vim:49:  setlocal number' | awk -F: '{print $1,"and",$2}'
after/ftplugin/python.vim and 49
```

But give us data before `grep`.  It may be that we can cut it more down.  No need for both  `grep` and `awk`

Answer (score 1):

How about this?:

```
echo 'after/ftplugin/python.vim:49:  setlocal number' | cut -d: -f1-2 | sed -e 's/:/ and /'
```

Result:

```
after/ftplugin/python.vim and 49
```

Comment: Works but it it possible to assign to a variable and pass it back to Vim - any thoughts ? "And" was not meant literally actually . Also it breaks when extra : is there in the filename . Need to reverse parse it .